# Grails 3.0 adding an inline plugin

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-3.0

I created simple grails 3.0 applications using commands below:

1. create-app admin --profile=web
2. create-plugin core --profile=plugin

Now, I wanted to use core as an inline plugin in admin build, which is a web application.

We can easily do that in grails version < 3.0  in buildconfig. Where can I do that in grails 3.0. Every help is worth appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inplace plugins have been replaced by multi project Gradle builds. See the Grails 3 functional test suite for an example https://github.com/grails/grails3-functional-tests

Comment: Thanks @GraemeRocher, you saved my day posting this example. I was using `include '../myPlugin'` and my `dev war` was failing trying to build the jar of `myPlugin`. After check the example, I changed to `include 'myPlugin'`   `project(':myPlugin').projectDir = new File('../myPlugin')` and everything works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Recently I used an inline plugin in my grails 3 application. here is how I did it-

1. Make sure that your application and your plugin are on same parent directory.
2. Now go to **build.gradle** file of your application.
3. Add this line in dependencies:
   `compile project(':plugin_name')`
4. Now go to **settings.gradle** file on your application and append these lines:
   `include 'plugin_name'`
   `project(':plugin_name').projectDir = new File('absolute_path_of_pluin')`

Comment: Thaks for that, is the best and complete answer that i could find, +1

Comment: I am glad that you found it useful.